# How to rotate a particle in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a particle which is an image. When I rotate the particle it leaves a circle behind. How do I get rid of this strange circle?

The Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zUvsp/137/

Code:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, material, img, texture, particle;
init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  scene.add(camera);

  img = new Image();
  texture = new THREE.Texture(img);

  img.onload = function() {
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    makeParticle();
  };
  img.src = "http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/davidcilley/files/PNG_Mask.png";

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function makeParticle() {
  material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  });
  // make the particle
  particle = new THREE.Particle(material);
  particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 1;
  particle.position.x = 10;
  scene.add(particle);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  particle.rotation.z += 0.01
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-EDIT
I tested my theory, its not the issue, don't waste your time

Just a guess, but I think it might have something to do with you loading the texture .png from a different domain.
Try using an image loaded from the same domain your code is running on, and see if that fixes the problem.

I think the issue might have something to do with three.js not being able to access the pixel data on the texture, because of the Cross-origin issue.